Date fields are serialized without quotes when imported Databricks Delta Table with struct column to Power BI
I have a Delta Table in Databricks with a column of struct type (containing a field of type date) and a column of type date:
create table date_struct (s struct<d:date>, d date, s_json string);
insert into date_struct (s, d, s_json) values (
    named_struct('d', '2020-01-01'), 
    '2020-02-01', 
    to_json(named_struct('d', '2020-01-01')))

When importing this date_struct table from Power BI, I get the following result (the s column is mapped to a string and the d column is mapped to a date):



s
d
s_json




{"d":2020-01-01}
01/02/2020
{"d":"2020-01-01"}



The value of the s column is a malformed JSON format (missing quotes on date 2020-01-01). As the JSON is malformed, the Power BI function Json.Document() cannot be used to convert the s string column into a JSON document e.g. when adding a new column. However, the same conversion works without error on the pre-serialized s_json column.
let
    Source = Databricks.Catalogs("xxx.azuredatabricks.net", "/sql/1.0/warehouses/yyy", [Catalog = "", Database = ""]),
    my_Database = Source{[Name="my",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    delta_tutorial_Schema = my_Database{[Name="myschema",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    ds1 = delta_tutorial_Schema{[Name="date_struct",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    ds2 = Table.AddColumn(ds1, "record_from_s", each Json.Document([s])),
    ds3 = Table.AddColumn(ds2, "record_from_s_json", each Json.Document([s_json]))
in
    ds3

gives the following error:



s
d
record_from_s
record_from_s_json




{"d":2020-01-01}
01/02/2020
Error
Record



DataFormat.Error: We found extra characters at the end of the JSON input.
Details:
    Value=-
    Position=9

What can I do to access the s.d field ?
Note that the above is a minimal example in order to reproduce the problem. The real use-case is another table with a much more complex struct and no pre-serialized s_json column. Thus, I want a reliable solution, not something like "use Json.Document() on the s_json column" or "add quotes on the s column with the Replace function".
Note 2: cross-posted to Databricks community forum.
